# Converting DisplayPort to 24 bit RGB parallel. Possible?

Tags: converter, display, rgb, displayport

Is it possible to interface a DP1.1 complaint source to a TFT Module that uses 24 bit RGB? I'm investigating the possibility of interfacing an Atom D2550 with [This Display.](http://www.trulydisplays.com/tft/specs/5.7in%20640x480%20TFT640480-8-E%20TP%20Spec.pdf)

I have 3 options to connect the Atom to the display: displayport, HDMI or VGA.

Based on comments, displayport would be the most difficult one. I guess it's either HDMI/DVi for VGA.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a little embedded Atom system? If so I'd be very surprised if "raw panel" wasn't an option already. At least it's YOUR system so you do not have to worry about HDCP/DPCP. Many companies provide HDMI receivers that lack HDCP; you could interface that relatively painlessly I think.

Answer (score 2):

[DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) is very similar to HDMI, although I would consider it a higher-level communications standard than HDMI. This means it'd be more complex to convert a DisplayPort signal to a "raw" panel format, but it's certainly possible. To start with, you'll need either some kind of receiver IC, perhaps something along the lines of what [ST](http://www.st.com/internet/imag_video/subclass/1385.jsp) or [IDT](http://www.idt.com/products/interface-connectivity/video-interface-products/panelport-displayport-solutions/displayport-receivers) offer (note EOL on second link) or, alternatively, you can make your own in an FPGA. If you go the latter route, [there](http://www.altera.com/products/ip/dsp/image_video_processing/m-bit-displayport-receiver.html) [are](http://www.cast-inc.com/ip-cores/interfaces/dprx-ctrl/index.html) [several](http://www.analogix.com/products/9830.html) IP cores available, or you can roll your own. The receivers spit out LVTTL data which may or may not need additional translation or physical conversion to fit to your particular panel.

It's not a simple task, there is a lot of high frequency digital signalling flying around any board designed to do this, but it'd be a fun little project.

If you're looking for more of a kit and less of a build-your-own solution you could take a look at several vendors on ebay; a quick search found lots of items [like this](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/HDMI-VGA-2AV-Driver-board-7inch-800-480-AT070TN92-V-5-Lcd-with-touch-panel-/170937641798?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27ccad6b46&_uhb=1#ht_6086wt_923), but they are all HDMI or DVI or VGA to flat-panel, not DisplayPort. You could always contact them and see what they say, but I imagine they'll want to sell you a HDMI/DVI to flat panel board with a [DisplayPort to DVI converter](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Griffin-Technology-GC17096-Mini-DisplayPort-to-HDMI-or-DVI-Converter-NEW-/380536412864?pt=US_Video_Cables_Adapters&hash=item5899bcdac0&_uhb=1#ht_4140wt_1301). :-/

Finally... a cautionary note: DisplayPort has its own version of HDCP called DPCP; you need to make sure that whatever you settle on handles that, or your video source may refuse to display anything even though your hardware is perfect. I didn't take a close enough look at ST's receivers but I know there are many HDMI receiver ICs that do have the option of internal HDCP controllers (along with a price increase, an NDA and other legal instruments)... that's probably your cheapest option if you *must* support DPCP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The good thing is that the Atom D2550 has HDMI also, which I could also use to connect. I'm thinking of doing my own solution as this will be a commercial product that will need support for about 5 years. Buying something from eBay won't give me a guarantee that I will be able to purchase it in 1000s pieces for the next 5 years. I have 3 options to connect the Atom to the display: displayport, HDMI or VGA.

Comment: @GustavoCorona You could go for a prebuilt kit for a first prototype, then once the kinks are ironed out, reverse-engineer the kit to figure out its BoM, as well as possible enhancements / part replacements.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh there may be "demo" boards for the receivers available too; those generally come with full schematics and are designed to be incorporated into a new design.